# How to insert a hyperlink inside a ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have created a new project in asp.net and i'm struggling to insert a hyperlink inside a ternary operator.

**Here is code snippet:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-Width="100">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <a href='<%# Eval("Status", "Questions/{0}.aspx") %>'>'<%# Eval("Status") %>'</a>
           <%# Eval("Status").ToString() == "A" ? "Absent" : "Present"  %>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In this above code, if the Status is "A", i need to insert the hyperlink (`<a href='<%# Eval("Status", "Questions/{0}.aspx") %>'>'<%# Eval("Status") %>'</a>`) in the place of "`Absent`".

**Here is my Output:**

[image]

How can i do this? Any advice would be healpful. Thank you.

**Update #1**:

I need only the absent to be the link, for present, i'm just displaying it as a plain text.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='Questions/Absent.aspx' 
       Text='<%# Eval("Status") %>' Visible='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Status").ToString() == "A" ? "True" : "False")) %>'>
  </asp:HyperLink>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='Present' Visible='<%#  Convert.ToBoolean((Eval("Status").ToString() == "A" ? "False" : "True")) %>'>
  </asp:Label>

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks @jaydipj for the quick response, but i need to display a link only for absent not for present. So if i use this code, i'll get links for both absent and present.

Comment: i need link only for absent, display present as plain text. please see my updated question for the visual representation. thanks

Comment: @RanjithVaradan Right now I am nt able to see you updated  Visual representation since this site is restricted. still I tried to imaging what you are expecting to do. Try Updated Ans Here I made Hyperlink visible only when its status is "A". Other wise this link will not be visible.

Comment: let me explain it more clearly, when i run the program, i get two 'absent' and two 'present'. Instead of 'absent', i need to display the 'absent' link. but for 'present', i just need to display 'present' as text, no link for present.

Comment: Thanks for the response but i'm getting an error  'Error 6 Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation 'Eval("Status").ToString() == "A" ? "False" : "True")' for the 'Visible' property. C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\GridView_Eval_IF_Condition\CS.aspx 57 '

Comment: Thanks @JaydipJ, You are a genius. It works perfect.